# Uniform convergence of functions, Spring 2002

Tags: general-topology, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, convergence-divergence

The question I have in mind is (see [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=-FornVjAz5UC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Berkeley%20Problems%20in%20Mathematics&source=bl&ots=efg-BqARmJ&sig=e7w4u5OsgKM2RSotkr9zbeRTkdo&hl=en&src=bmrr&sa=X&ei=YgARULOEIsal6AHG-4HgCw&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), page [60](http://books.google.com/books?id=-FornVjAz5UC&pg=PA60), the solution is at page [297](http://books.google.com/books?id=-FornVjAz5UC&pg=PA297)):

Assume $f_{n}$ is a sequence of functions from a metric space $X$ to $Y$. Suppose $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly and has inverse $g_{n}$. Now assume $f$'s inverse $g$ is uniformly continuous on $Y$. Prove that $g_{n}\rightarrow g$ uniformly.

I could not prove it using standard techniques as I do not know how to bound $|g_{n}(y)-g(y)|$ when $n$ becomes very large. The authors argue that the convergence of $g_{n}(y)\rightarrow g(y)$ is similar to $f(g_{n}(y))\rightarrow f(g(y))$ because the mapping by a uniformly convergent function series keeps uniform convergence. Thus they give the following argument that $$d(f(g(y)),f(g_{n}(y)))=d(y,f(g_{n}(y)))\le d(y,f_{n}(g_{n}(y)))+d(f_{n}(g_{n}(y)),f(g_{n}(y)))=d(f_{n}(g_{n}(y)),f(g_{n}(y)))$$

So since $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly by hypothesis the statement is proved. My question is: Is the step of substituting $|g_{n}(y)-g(y)|$ by $|f(g(y))-f(g_{n}(y))|$ really justified? I could not get the "keep uniform convergence" thing the author is talking about. But I also could not come up with a better proof.

Comment: It's interesting, at no point did the proof use any claim about one function being the inverse of another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $h_n\colon S\to S'$ converges uniformly to $h$ on $S$ and $\varphi\colon S'\to S''$ is uniformly continuous on $S$, fix $\varepsilon>0$. There is a $\delta>0$ such that if $d_{S'}(x,y)\leq \delta$ then $d_{S''}(\varphi(x),\varphi(y))\leq\varepsilon)$. Now, we use the fact that there is an integer $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, we have 
$$\sup_{x\in S}d_S(h_n(x),h(x))\leq \delta.$$
Then 
$$\sup_{x\in S}d_S(\varphi(h_n(x)),\varphi(h(x)))\leq\varepsilon.$$
Now, we apply this result with $\varphi=g$ and $h_n:=f\circ g_n$.

Comment: In translation we have $|f(g_{n})-f(g)|\le \delta$ when $n\ge N$, and $|g(x)-g(y)|\le \epsilon$ when $|x-y|\le \delta$. Thus we have $|g(y)-g_{n}(y)|=|g(f(g(y))-g(f(g_{n}(y))|\le \delta$ once $n\ge N$. But this feels wierd - why would $f(g_{n})$ converges uniformly to $g$?

Comment: Sorry I was confused. I should have written $f(g_{n})$ to $f(g)=I$.

Comment: Davide, where are you..?

Comment: It has been shown that $f\circ g_n$ converges uniformly to $f\circ g$. By what I showed, $g\circ f\circ g_n$ converges uniformly to $g\circ f\circ g$, that is $g_n$ converges uniformly to $g$.

Comment: Davide, I do not think it is given $f\circ g_{n}$ converges to $I$ uniformly. We only know $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly and $g_{n}\rightarrow g$, the later's uniformity is skeptical unless we proved it.

Comment: It's proved in the correction, since $$\sup_{y\in Y}d(f(g(y)),f(g_n(y)))\leq \sup_{y\in Y}d(f_n(g_n(y),f(g_n(y))\leq \sup_{x\in X}d(f_n(x),f(x)).$$

Comment: I see the subtlety. Thanks!